# Selenium C#: Locate element on chart

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I want to identify the stimulusFrequency circles on this chart so I can click and drag them.[image]

```
<svg class="svg-graph-content graphEventHandler ng-valid" ng-model="hearingGraph" viewBox="0 0 470 355" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<path class="" ng-show="audiogram.leftEnabled" ep-d="M42 148.39999389648438 L126 148.71843558091385 L210 147.23333740234375 L294 147.86266635014462 L378 147.86266635014462 L462 147.86266635014462" fill-opacity="0" stroke-width="2" stroke="rgb(0,0,255)" d="M42 148.39999389648438 L126 148.71843558091385 L210 147.23333740234375 L294 147.86266635014462 L378 147.86266635014462 L462 147.86266635014462" style="">
<circle class="" ng-touch="manualGraph($event, c, 'left')" ng-mousedown="manualGraph($event, c, 'left')" ng-show="audiogram.leftEnabled && manual" ng-repeat="c in audiogram.tonePoints | filter: {'resultSet': 'left'} | orderBy : 'stimulusFrequency'" fill="black" ep-r="8" ep-cy="148.39999389648438" ep-cx="42" cy="148.39999389648438" cx="42" r="8">
```

The part of the chart I want to interact with is the "circle class", using firebug, I found the XPath for one of this circles as below but I got a "No such element" exception.

```
.//*[@id='layout-wrapper']/ui-view/ui-view/div/ep-annotation-widget/div/div/div/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/svg/circle[1]
```

I have made some progress by using:

```
var circles = Driver.Instance.FindElements(By.TagName("circle"));
```

But this gives 27 results when there should only be 12 so I will keep working on it.

Comment: Can't you  identify particular circle for selection by one (or combination) of it's attribute value? That can be translated into xpath expression easily, f.e `//circle[@cx=42 and @r=8]`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with. Please let me know if you have a more efficient way.

```
    public static void MoveNode(string ear, int frequency)
    {
        int circleRef = 0;
        switch (frequency)
        {
            case 250:
                if (ear == "right")
                {
                    circleRef = 12;
                }
                else if (ear == "left")
                {
                    circleRef = 0;
                }
                break;
            case 500:
                if (ear == "right")
                {
                    circleRef = 13;
                }
                else if (ear == "left")
                {
                    circleRef = 1;
                }
                break;
        }
        var circles = Driver.Instance.FindElements(By.TagName("circle"));
        circles[circleRef].Click();
        //add logic for dragging and releasing
    }
```